# Formatting a conversation

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, novel, dialogue, formatting

In a novel, how would one best represent a recorded conversation between two people played back to a larger audience? The normal rules apply regarding quotation marks and beginning a new paragraph every time someone begins to speak but should the recorded conversation be italicized? Should the narration pertaining to the recorded conversation be within the same paragraph or separate? The answer is probably obvious and I may well be overthinking this but any help would be swell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direct thoughts](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/17141/direct-thoughts). An answer to that question answers this question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally, ***italics*** are used to mark up voices from a device in fiction.

---

[This answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/17142/40570) lists the conventional uses of italics.